# Where compiled code will be stored if not in class file

Tags: java, compiler-construction, jvm, .class-file, java-compiler-api

Recently I came across a query while reading *[THE STRUCTURE OF THE JAVA VIRTUAL MACHINE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/jvms7.pdf)*

On page no-5 ch. 2,

> Compiled code to be executed by the Java Virtual Machine is
>   represented using a hardware- and operating system-independent binary
>   format, typically (but not necessarily) stored in a file, known as the
>   class file format.

That bracket **But not necessarily** is the reason.

Question is,

In which case compiled code will not be stored in class file ? and if it will not be stored in class file, then where and how ?

**Edit :** Please note that question is not about ClassLoader.

Comment: Well you could keep it in a byte[] in memory, or in a database for example.

Comment: @PeterLiljenberg and this will be defined by compiler, right ?

Comment: The java compiler is just a java class that you can invoke so yes the output will be determined by the compiler implementation. Read more in the official docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem more interest in how to generate a java class file in memory so here goes:

```
public class CompileSourceInMemory {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new    DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(writer);
        out.println("public class HelloWorld {");
        out.println("  public static void main(String args[]) {");
        out.println("    System.out.println(\"This is in another java file\");");    
        out.println("  }");
        out.println("}");
        out.close();
        JavaFileObject file = new JavaSourceFromString("HelloWorld", writer.toString());

        Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = Arrays.asList(file);
        CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, null, diagnostics, null, null, compilationUnits);

        boolean success = task.call();

        if (success) {
            try {
                Class.forName("HelloWorld").getDeclaredMethod("main", new Class[] { String[].class }).invoke(null, new Object[] { null });
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                System.err.println("Class not found: " + e);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                System.err.println("No such method: " + e);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                System.err.println("Illegal access: " + e);
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                System.err.println("Invocation target: " + e);
            }
        }
    }
}

class JavaSourceFromString extends SimpleJavaFileObject {
    final String code;

    JavaSourceFromString(String name, String code) {
        super(URI.create("string:///" + name.replace('.','/') + Kind.SOURCE.extension),Kind.SOURCE);
        this.code = code;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getCharContent(boolean ignoreEncodingErrors) {
        return code;
    }
}
```

**Source:** [In memory compilation](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JDK-6/CompilingfromMemory.htm)

This generates a class in memory without any external representation of the java source or compiled class.

Answer (score 3):

In java, where a classloader gets the binary compiled from depends on it's implementation.
It's possible to write a class loader that loads it's classes from a database, from the net, from memory or any other thinkable location.

The default java [URLClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) uses files in directories or jars, so that's where the "typically" comes from, the "not necessarily" is just a hint that there may be other implementations.

Comment: Thats about loading class from compiled code, what about generating compiled code ?

Comment: That's just anohter special case. The code would be generated/compiled in memory and then loaded by the class loader...

Answer (score 2):

Storing compiled code in a .class file is only the standard and more convenient way of getting executable code for a JVM, however, the same compiled code can be obtained from many other sources, it could be obtained as a text or binary stream from a DB or from a network connection or from memory at runtime, [check this example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JDK-6/CompilingfromMemory.htm) or [this one](http://www.javablogging.com/dynamic-in-memory-compilation/)

Comment: Thats about obtaining generated compiled code, what about generating compiled code ? +1 for *Thats about loading class from compiled code, what about generating compiled code ?*

Comment: Check the links, and this too http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this question is about Classloader!

The Classloader is the (only) way the JVM brings in classes. The classes could be in files, JAR archives, somewhere on the network, in a database blob, in shared memory, on paper tape (if your machine has a paper tape reader) or they could even be generated on the fly.

So, this is the answer to your question.

The standard compiler uses to write class files, but, as Peter commented, this is not necessarily so. And, above all, just because the javac command writes class files that does not mean we must use those files. It is common to pack them in a JAR, and use that instead.